# Azure DevOps Server: Why does a current version of ADS require a patch for a prior version of ADS?

Tags: azure, version, patch

I installed Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.1 (Product Version: 18.181.31527.1, ADS 2020 Update 1.1, Release date: 8/17/2021) on an application server and configured it successfully. My security guy ran a Nessus vulnerability scan and Nessus reports that the app server fails [Security Updates for Microsoft Team Foundation Server and Azure DevOps Server (April 2021)](https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/148714) (Nessus vulnerability check #148714). In other words, it seems I need to install a patch from April 2021 for ADS 2020 Update 0.1 to cure a vulnerability for ADS 2020 Update 1.1 released in August 2021

The Nessus solution says this:

> Microsoft has released the following updates:
>
> - Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.1 with patch 8
> - Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 0.1 with patch 2
>
> Additionally, Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 3.1 through Azure
> DevOps 2020.0.1 require resource group task(s) to be manually applied.

So, this Nessus description says the fix for my ADS 2020 instance is to apply Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 0.1 patch 2 and it provides a link to [April patches for Azure DevOps Server and Team Foundation Server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/april-patches-for-azure-devops-server-and-team-foundation-server-2/). The description for ADS 2020 0.1 with patch 2 includes **VERY** involved tasks `AzureResourceGroupDeploymentV2` and `AzureResourceGroupDeploymentV3`.

Why would a version of ADS 2020 released August 2021 require patches published for a prior version of ADS 2020. This makes no sense.

p.s. I put this same question on the [Microsoft Developer Community board](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-server-202011-release-date-8172021-is/1515292?from=email&viewtype=all#T-ND1535256) 3 weeks ago but have not received an answer/solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has performed a re-release of the 2020.1.1 version with an increased version number; 18.181.31527.1. The solution is to repair the Azure DevOps installation, then update to the re-release version and then apply patch 1. I have a full overview of all versions of Azure DevOps Server and TFS (https://github.com/FokkoVeegens/AzureDevOpsServerVersions), which I will update accordingly, so thanks for your question ;).

Comment: Thank-you!  When I get current fires put out, I'll dive deeper into your answer and resources.

Comment: Your steps are: 1) repair the ADS installation; 2) update to the re-release version; 3) apply patch 1. I understand step 3, but not step 1 or 2. Please provide details for step 1 (I don't understand what you mean by "repair the Azure DevOps installation"). For step 2:  where did you get the re-release of 2020 1.1? When I go to my.visualstudio.com (My Visual Studio subscription page), the most recent version I see for 2020 1.1 is still dated 8/17/2021. Also, not a show-stopper, but the link you provided to the dev community question is dead - the question appears to have been removed

Comment: Step 1 is a repair which is available from the **Apps** or **Features and Programs** control panel. Find the Azure DevOps Server entry and choose **Change**. It starts the Azure DevOps Server installer and from there you can choose **Repair**. Step 2: The version you currently have is not available anymore. Both versions were released on the same day. If you now download 2020.1.1 from the site, it will download the fixed version. I see they removed the thread; I will update the link in my answer, thanks for the heads-up.